# Vertical line in ymode=log plot

Tags: pgfplots

Please have a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            %ymode=log,
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
            (0, 6.887e-02)
            (0.5, 3.177e-02)
            (1, 1.341e-02)
            (1.5, 5.334e-03)
            (2, 2.027e-03)
            (2.5, 7.415e-04)
            (3, 2.628e-04)
            (3.5, 9.063e-05)
            (4, 3.053e-05)
            };
            \draw (axis cs:1.2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1.2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces a graph like this (some data with a vertical line at x=1.2):

[image: some data with a vertical line at x=1.2]

As soon as I uncomment ymode=log, the vertical line disappears. Bummer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `\draw ({axis cs:1.2,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:1.2,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1})` to draw the vertical line from the top of the plot area to the bottom. This command looks a bit intimidating at first, but it's really not that bad:

The point `rel axis cs:0,0` is the lower left corner of the plot area, `rel axis cs:0,1` is the upper left corner. The syntax `(A|-B)` specifies the point that lies at the intersection of a vertical line through `A` and a horizontal line through `B` (put another way, we're using the `x` coordinate of `A` and the `y` coordinate of B). When using `axis cs` and `rel axis cs` in the coordinate specification, they need to be grouped in `{...}` to hide the commas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymode=log,
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
            (0, 6.887e-02)
            (0.5, 3.177e-02)
            (1, 1.341e-02)
            (1.5, 5.334e-03)
            (2, 2.027e-03)
            (2.5, 7.415e-04)
            (3, 2.628e-04)
            (3.5, 9.063e-05)
            (4, 3.053e-05)
            };
            \draw ({axis cs:1.2,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:1.2,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's strange that I can't make `\pgfmathparse{pow(10,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})}` work to get back the original value.

Comment: @percusse: You can get them back with `\pgfplotsextra{
             \pgfmathsetmacro\ymin{exp(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})}
             \pgfmathsetmacro\ymax{exp(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})}
             \draw (axis cs:1.2,\ymin) -- (axis cs:1.2,\ymax);
            }`, but there seems to be a numerical error (the line doesn't go all the way to the bottom), and it's a bit too labour intensive for my liking.

Comment: Indeed it is but still it would have been great to have `yminlog` and `ymaxlog` keys to get it running for `semilogyaxis` environment etc.

Comment: @percusse you are right; that should probably be fixed... on first sight, it seems as if exp() should be applied by pgfplots when it defines the /pgfplots/ymin limits...

Comment: @Jake the approach with pgfmathsetmacro uses pgf math - which is unsuitable for such data ranges. Using something with extended precision (like `/pgf/fpu`) would solve the issue. Keep in mind that `\pgfmathsetmacro` will *always* assign the result to some TeX register (for whatever reason). Thus, `/pgf/fpu` + `\pgfmathparse{...}\let\ymin=\pgfmathresult` would fix your code snippet.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Ah yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Actually I tried fpu but it was still off. Maybe I wasn't careful enough.

Answer (score 2):

With PGFPlots 1.11 or later, Jake's solution could be made a little less intimidating with the following equivalent syntax.

```
\draw (1.2,0 |- current axis.south) -- (1.2,0 |- current axis.north);
```

Since that version, `axis cs` has been the default and therefore can be omitted. I find TikZ's anchors (a property of any node, of which a PFGPlots axis is one) easier to use than `rel axis cs`. Without coordinate specifiers, there's no need for braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} % <=== or later
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymode=log,
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
            (0, 6.887e-02)
            (0.5, 3.177e-02)
            (1, 1.341e-02)
            (1.5, 5.334e-03)
            (2, 2.027e-03)
            (2.5, 7.415e-04)
            (3, 2.628e-04)
            (3.5, 9.063e-05)
            (4, 3.053e-05)
            };
            \draw (1.2,0 |- current axis.south) -- (1.2,0 |-
            current axis.north);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```